# How To Add UTC Offset to current date

Tags: c#

at the moment I need to determine what timezone is currently "9am". I have a table to timezones and their offsets plus taking into consideration daylight savings

The offsets are stored in my database as +/- time.

For example, LA/Vancouver is `-8:00`

The approach I was going to take was to iterate through all time zones, convert the offset so I can `addhours` and `addminutes` to DateTime.UtcNow then check if the hour is 9.  The only issue I see is that it's not able to handle daylight savings.

I was wondering is there are any existing libraries I can leverage for my scenario or a better approach to the one I suggested? In the end I require the ID column.

Timezones table

[image]

Comment: What is "9AM" - how is it stored? In other words, what is the point of reference when "9AM" was created (UTC, local, etc.)?

Comment: [TimeZoneInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo) has already these informations available. You need to store a DateTime object to determine, eventually, an offset. If you save a string, that's it.

Comment: Be aware that there will sometimes be multiple time zones where it's 9 AM, and there might be some times when it's not 9 AM for any time zone. See [Falsehoods programmers believe about time](https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relatively easy to do using the built-in .NET classes `TimeZoneInfo` and `DateTime`, but you might be surprised by the results.

```
from z in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
let timeThere = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, z)
where timeThere.Hour == 9
select new{z.DisplayName, timeThere}
```

For example, right now there are 7 time zones that my machine is aware of in which it's in the 9 AM hour.

[image]

Comment: I definitely liked your approach but unfortunately I also need to leverage my timezones table. I require the Id columns.

Comment: @Phoenix: Nothing wrong with that. There's a `TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone()` method that you can use to generate a list of `TimeZoneInfo`s from your table's data, and you can substitute that list in the place of `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` in my code. You can either use your ID as the TimeZoneInfo's ID string, or use a tuple or class or anonymous type to pair each ID to its TimeZoneInfo so you can select the ID after applying the `where` criteria.

Comment: Do be aware that without knowing the daylight savings time and other adjustment rules associated with those time zones, your table's data will be wrong much of the time.